# Consume MSK topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, aws-msk

I am working on a AWS MSK consumer project, where I am looking to develop/test my application before deploying to EMR. However I am not aware how to configure my local to consume from my MSK kafka cluster, which is in VPC.

I tried reading my subscribing to kafka brokers and the particular topic.

```
streaming_query = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("<kafka-brokers>").option("subscribe",input_topic).load()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You have several options with different ports/addresses, depending on where the code is ran.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/client-access.html

I suggest you add a CLI flag / enum / boolean variable to determine where you've executed the code, from local or within the VPC